# Non-degenerate representation of a Banach algebra

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, c-star-algebras, banach-algebras

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a non-reflexive Banach algebra. For the definition of Arens product, please refer to this [link](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Arens_multiplication). Here we let $\square$ denote the first Arens product and $\diamond$ denote the second Arens product. Let $\pi: \mathcal{A} \rightarrow \mathcal{A}^{\ast\ast}$ be the canonical embedding. For each $a\in \mathcal{A}$, define:

$$
L_a: \mathcal{A}^{\ast\ast} \rightarrow \mathcal{A}^{\ast\ast}, \hspace{0.3cm} A\mapsto a\square A
$$

and:

$$
R_a: \mathcal{A}^{\ast\ast} \rightarrow \mathcal{A}^{\ast\ast}, \hspace{0.3cm} A\mapsto A\diamond a
$$

Then the mapping $L: a\mapsto L_a$ defines a representation of $\mathcal{A}$. My question is:

1. When $\mathcal{A} \square \mathcal{A}^{\ast\ast}$ (resp. $\mathcal{A}^{\ast\ast} \diamond \mathcal{A}$) is dense with respect to the norm topology, or equivalently, $\big[ L(\mathcal{A})(\mathcal{A}^{\ast\ast}) \big]^{\perp}$ (resp. $\big[ R(\mathcal{A})(\mathcal{A}^{\ast\ast}) \big]^{\perp}$) is $0$?
2. In the case when $\mathcal{A}$ has a bounded approximate unit (with respect to the norm topology) $(a_i)_{i\in I}$, let $E$ be a weak-$\ast$ cluster point of $\big\{ \pi(a_i) \big\}_{i\in I}$. Then when $E$ is THE unit of the Banach algebra $\big( \mathcal{A}^{\ast\ast}, \square \big)$, or $\big( \mathcal{A}^{\ast\ast}, \diamond \big)$?

**Update**: In the case when $\mathcal{A}$ has an approximate unit, one can show that $A\square E = E\diamond A = A$. Then define:

$$
Z\big( \mathcal{A}^{\ast\ast}, \square \big) = \big\{ A\in\mathcal{A}^{\ast\ast}: \forall\, B\in \mathcal{A}^{\ast\ast},\, A\square B = B\square A \big\}
$$
In the case when $\mathcal{A}$ has an approximate unit, I proved that $\mathcal{A} \subseteq Z\big( \mathcal{A}^{\ast\ast}, \square \big)$ if and only if any cluster points of $\big\{ \pi(a_i) \big\}_{i\in I}$ commutes with all elements in $\mathcal{A}^{\ast\ast}$ with respect to the both Arens products. However, I wonder if there is a necessary condition on $\mathcal{A}$ that implies such $E$ is a unit and unique.

Comment: I recommend changing the title, since neither of your questions have anything to do with irreducibility: if D is a Banach algebra and M is a left Banach D-module, then knowing that D$\cdot$M is dense in M says nothing about whether M is irreducible or not. (Consider D being the complex numbers, acting by scalar multiplication.)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out since I struggled with looking for a better title for a while. Here the "irreducible" does not mean a "simple module" but I want to make it similar to a irreducible representation of a $C^*$-algebra. For instance, given a $C^*$-algebra $A$ and a $\ast$-representation $\pi: A\rightarrow B(H)$, $\pi$ is irreducible if $\pi(A)(H)$ is dense in $H$ (like my first question), or equivalently $\pi(A)'$ is trivial (like my second question). Please feel free to edit the title if you find a better word.

Comment: That condition defines a _nondegenerate_ representation, not an irreducible one.  And it's not equivalent to the commutant being trivial...

Comment: @MatthewDaws has already pointed out your error concerning terminology, but also please reread my initial comment and note that ${\mathbb C}$ is a perfectly good ${\rm C}^\ast$-algebra and the homomorphism which sends $\lambda$ to $\lambda I_2$ is a perfectly good star-representation on a Hilbert space which satisfies your density condition but is clearly not an irreducible representation, in any sense.

Comment: Regarding your questions, are you aware of Arens regularity and some of the standard examples of Banach algebras that are not Arens regular?

Comment: @MatthewDaws Sorry for the confusion and I could not find a word to describe the which property I am looking for. The first question is related to "non-degenerate" but I do not know how to describe the second one.

Comment: @YemonChoi Sorry for the confusion and it would be more rigorous to only consider non-reflexive Banach algebra. I do not know many examples of Arens irregular Banach algebras except those mentioned in the link. For the second question, $\ell_1$ equipped with point-wise multiplication has a unbounded approximate unit that has a unique weak-$\ast$ cluster point on $\ell_{\infty}^*$, so I am tempted to remove "bounded".

Comment: In your last comment, why do you claim that the unbounded approximate unit for $\ell_1$ has a weak-star cluster point? If I recall correctly, the bidual of $\ell_1$ with pointwise product does not have an identity element.

Comment: Also, it is immediate from the definition of Arens regularity that if A is Arens regular then Q2 has a positive answer.

Comment: Finally: if an algebra has a 2-sided identity element then this is necessarily unique. (This is an elementary calculation that has nothing to do with Banach algebras.)